# How to get to Authorized part in Xcode UI Tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation

I have the app with login screen and the screen that appear after login (authorized part).

What is the best approach to test these screens from Authorized part?

I have several ideas:

1) Somehow I need to remove all the data from keychain before each test and then I go through the entire flow each time to get to the first screen after login. When I need to send a request to backend to login, I wait for the main screen using

```
let nextGame = self.app.staticTexts["Main Screen Text"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWithObject: nextGame, handler: nil)
waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
```

2) I pass some arguments here

```
app = XCUIApplication(bundle:….)
    app.launchArguments = [“notEmptyArguments”:”value”]
    app.launch()
```

So I can pass a fake `token` and out backend will accept this `token`, so that my app will know that it has to route me to the Main Screen and all the requests will be successful because my Network Service has this fake `token`

But I fill that it's a not vary safe way.

*Do you have any ideas what is the best approach and may be you can give advice of a better approach?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second idea you mentioned is a good way to skip login screen in tests. Furthermore, implementing token passing will be helpful to developer team as well. Those launch arguments can be stored at running schemes settings.

Also, if you implement deep linking in the same manner it will bring even more speed enhancements for both QA and developer team.

Surely, these "shortcuts" shall be only accessible while running a `debug` configuration (using `#if DEBUG...`)

Comment: thank you for your thoughts, for now I'm marking your answer as correct unless someone else gives some new ideas how to archive that purposes

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your Login Service or whatever `service` your app might need to perform or show some use cases, should be all `mocked`. That means in your automated `unit/ui testing` environment your app is going to talk to mocked service implementations, that means that the login service or authorization service response should be mocked to either be success or failure, so you can test both of them.

To achieve that your services should all be represented as interfaces/`protocols` and the implementation/implementation details should be in either the production, development or automated `testing` environment.

I would never involve any networking in automated testing. You should create a mock implementation of your authorization service for example that in automated test environment could be mocked to either give a response of success or failure depending on the test you are running (and this setup you can do in the setup() method maybe).

Comment: This is true for Unit Tests and I do them the same way, but that's impossible for UI Tests, because UI Tests launch your real application on a simulator

Comment: It is possible to detect if application is launched by test run (you'll need another launch argument). Then, you can switch to a fake server if needed. The other (and sometimes better) way to mock things in UI-test is to use EarlGrey framework, though it is still in beta.

Answer (score 1):

The most authentic test suite would sign in at the beginning of each test (if needed) and would sign out if appropriate during teardown. This keeps each test self-contained and allows each test to use a different set of credentials without needing to check if it's already signed in/needs to change to a different user account, because tests will always sign out at the end.

This is not a fool-proof method as it may not always be possible for teardown code to execute correctly if a test has failed (since the app may not be in the state that teardown expects, depending on your implementation) but if you are looking for end-to-end tests, using only the codepaths used by production users, this is one way you could do it.

Introducing mocking/stubbing can make your tests more independent and reliable - it's up to you to choose how much you want to mirror the production user experience in your tests.